# Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I'm using SQLite3
I have a columns but the error says that column "undefined" is not created.

```
const SQLite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new SQLite.Database('./database.sqlite');
db.serialize(function() {
db.run(`INSERT INTO users (id, name, soul, money, level, exp, items, weapon, 
armor, inbattle) VALUES(${message.author.id}, ${message.author.name}, 
"determination", 0, 1, 0, "DogFood", "Stick", "Bandage", "False");`);
})
```

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix of another error was adding the "" to ${message.author.username}.
Final code:

```
const SQLite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new SQLite.Database('./database.sqlite');
db.serialize(function() {
db.run(`INSERT INTO users (id, name, soul, money, level, exp, items, weapon, 
armor, inbattle) VALUES("${message.author.id}", "${message.author.username}", 
"determination", 0, 1, 0, "DogFood", "Stick", "Bandage", "False");`);
})
```

Comment: After more than year I realise that it's very wrong way to do that. Use `?` to put data into the database.

Comment: For some more info, one reason why this method is a terrible idea is because, unless you do your own input sanitisation, you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Using the `?` method handles input sanitisation for you.